# Run Program as Administrator on CrossOver/Wine

Tags: wine, crossover

I'm playing Need for Speed Underground 2 on Ubuntu using CrossOver. The problem is, in order to plan on LAN I need to run NFSU2 as Administrator but I do not know how to do this on CrossOver. For example when my brother plays on his windows PC he right clicks the game and clicks "Run as Administrator".

For some reason this is the only way in order to play on LAN. I cant seem to right click nor run NFSU2 as administrator. I have searched everywhere online but haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

CrossOver **ALWAYS** claims you're administrator, but not always successes on LAN.

You'll want everyone you want to play LAN with to install Hamachi, and you all join a single network; Then, when you open a LAN game, if you connect using an IP, you'll want to use your Hamachi IP, which I believe usually is something like 5.x.x.x

Comment: For this game, even on a windows administrator account my brother still has to right click and run it as admin. I just need a way to make it so NFSU2 always runs as admin. I used wine explorer to find the .exe and right clicked. I pressed on properties but no dialog appeared. Any reason why?